# The renewal function for pure process

Tags: probability, renewal-processes

In the derivation of the renewal function, I have seen two different formulas which differ by $1$ as follows. Let $N_t$ be a pure renewal process with jump distribution $F$ and $S_n=\sum^n X_i$, then
\begin{align} \mathbb EN_t &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb P(N_t >n) \\ 
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(N_t \geq n)-\mathbb P(N_t=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(S_n \leq t) -1 \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty F^{\star n}(t)-1
\end{align}

But also from Asmussens book
\begin{align} \mathbb EN_t &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb P(N_t >n) \\ 
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(S_n\leq t)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty F^{\star n}(t)
\end{align}

And in Liao's book
$$\mathbb E N_t=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(S_n\leq t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty F^{\star n}(t)$$

The first has the problem that $\mathbb P(N_t \geq n)=\mathbb P(S_n< t)$ which is fixed in Asmussens book and the third I can make sense of if I set $F^{\star 0}=1$ to agree with the first. How do I make sense of Asmussens one in relation to the other 2.

Answer (score 0):

Define $m(t) = \mathbb E[N_t]$ where $N_t = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathsf 1_{[0,t]}(S_n)$. Then
$$m(t) =  \mathbb E\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathsf 1_{[0,t]}(S_n)\right] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(S_n\leqslant t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F^{n*}(t),$$
where the interchange of summation with expectation is justified by Tonelli's theorem (all summands are nonnegative). Note that $S_n\leqslant t$ iff $\mathsf 1_{[0,t]}(S_n)=1$, so $\mathbb E[\mathsf 1_{[0,t]}(S_n)] = \mathbb P(S_n\leqslant t)$.

Asmussen's text states
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[N_t] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(N_t>n)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(S_n\leqslant t)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n\leqslant t)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty F^{*n}(t) = m(t),
\end{align}
which is consistent with $S_0=Y_0=0$ a.s.

Comment: Okay what about the other 2 solutions? The solution is just asmussens rewritten

Comment: The definition in Liao's book assumes there is no renewal at time $0$. As for deriving $\mathbb E[N(t)] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F^{*n}(t) - 1$, note that this is the same as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty F^{*n}(t)$.

Comment: I know but Asmussen starts the sum from 0 and assumes as well that the renewals are proper.